# existing user in app that already register as a user in firebase can send a data to firebase that can be only seen in the app specific to that user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to send pdf file to specific user in firebase and only show that pdf file to that user alone.

Send data to specific ID  in Firebase and retrieve and show only to that user.

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.OnProgressListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

public class uploadfile extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView imagebrowse,imageupload,filelogo,cancelfile;
Uri filepath;
EditText filetitle;

StorageReference storageReference;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
String uid;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploadfile);

getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

storageReference= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");

filetitle=findViewById(R.id.filetitle);

imagebrowse=findViewById(R.id.imagebrowse);
imageupload=findViewById(R.id.imageupload);

filelogo=findViewById(R.id.filelogo);
cancelfile=findViewById(R.id.cancelfile);

FirebaseUser user =firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
uid = user.getUid();
filelogo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
cancelfile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
cancelfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
filelogo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
cancelfile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
imagebrowse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });


imagebrowse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
Dexter.withContext(getApplicationContext())
                        .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                            @Override
public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setType("application/pdf");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Pdf Files"),101);
                            }

                            @Override
public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

                            }

                            @Override
public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                            }
                        }).check();
            }
        });

imageupload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
processupload(filepath);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(requestCode==101 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
filepath=data.getData();
filelogo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
cancelfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
imagebrowse.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }


public void processupload(Uri filepath)
    {


final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(this);
pd.setTitle("File Uploading....!!!");
pd.show();


final StorageReference reference=storageReference.child("uploads/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".pdf");
reference.putFile(filepath)

                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

model obj=new model(filetitle.getText().toString(),uri.toString(),0,0,0);
databaseReference.child(databaseReference.push().getKey()).setValue(obj);

pd.dismiss();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

filelogo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
cancelfile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
imagebrowse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
filetitle.setText("");
                            }
                        });

                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
float percent=(100*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred())/taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
pd.setMessage("Uploaded :"+(int)percent+"%");
                    }
                });


    }

}
```

Comment: Please format your code so we can understand what the problem really is.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. When you set a breakpoint on each line of your code, then run in the debugger, and check the value of each variable on each line, which is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

While login with that particular firebase user, you get the Uid i.e. the user id of user. While sending PDF file send also the user id everytime you upload PDF File

While fetching, fetch the collection with the same user id with which your app is logged in. Thanks